# Log to remote syslog server with Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, syslog

I would like to create logs to a Syslog Server (Kiwi Syslog Server, to be more precise) from ruby.

I don't want to log ruby or rails stuff to the syslog server. I want to create a pre-define log message when an event occurrs and log this to a remote server using their Kiwi Syslog Server.

Any clue on how to do that? (I'm using ruby 1.8.7 and rails 2.3.14)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby has a built in Syslog module you can use directly to write messages.

[1.9.3](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/syslog/rdoc/Syslog.html)
[1.8.7](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.8.7/libdoc/syslog/rdoc/Syslog.html)

Comment: Ok. But my system uses ruby 1.8.7. Can't do an update right now.

Comment: You are in luck, looks like 1.8.7 has it too. I updated the post.

Comment: I took a look on it, but I can't see how I could log to a remote server. 

These examples say how to log locally, aparentally.

Comment: That's normally setup on the local system syslog server. It sends it's log messages to a remote server. At that level you can control which messages get sent to the remote server as well. If you have questions on that part post at serverfault.com

Comment: Hi there. I have the same question. @ctcherry said above 'normally setup'. Does that mean an abnormal configuration whereby logs are sent direct an external syslog server is possible? Or is normal the only option?

Comment: Remote logging is possible, here's a guide I found: http://www.aboutdebian.com/syslog.htm